# sleep() C doesn't return the correct value

Tags: c, sleep

I am a doing a school project (need to develop it in C) and I need it to execute some code each X seconds and Y seconds after the execution of the program has started it must end.

So I wrote:

```
alarm(Y);
s=X;
while(!end){
    s = sleep(s); //because it generates some children that send signal to him and in that case i need to do other stuffs
    if(s == 0){
        //code to do each X seconds
    }
}
```

The variable `end` is a global variable initialized at 0 and when a SIGALARM is received the value becomes 1.

If I have got  X>Y the code to do each X seconds shouldn't be executed but if X=Y+1 it is executed once.

Could you tell me why this happens?

Comment: I'm not very clear, I understand you problem with English, but, can you be graphical?, like a time-line for operations?

Comment: [_mixing calls to alarm(2) and sleep() is a bad idea._](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)

Comment: If even the manual of sleep says mixing alarm and sleep is a bad idea, you shouldn't even think of doing that.

Comment: @Pere How did you arrive at the conclusion, please?

Answer (score 2):

[Per the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `sleep()` causes the calling thread to sleep either until the number
>   of real-time seconds specified in seconds have elapsed **or until a
>   signal arrives which is not ignored.**
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Zero if the requested time has elapsed, **or the number of seconds
>   left to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler.**

Your use of `alarm()` almost certainly interrupts your `sleep()` call.

And even if `alarm()` didn't interfere, `sleep()` can *always* be interrupted by a signal anyway, and you have to handle that appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with only `sleep()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned int const y = 5;
  unsigned int const x = 2;

  {
    unsigned int left = y;
    unsigned int action = 0;
    while (left > 0) {
      unsigned int time = x - action < left ? x - action : left;
      printf("I will sleep for %u\n", time);
      {
        unsigned ret = sleep(time);

        action += time - ret;
        if (action >= x) {
          printf("do something\n");
          action -= x;
        }

        left -= time - ret;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But note that it's clearly not accurate, there is better method that `sleep()` with POSIX standard like `clock_gettime()` and `nanosleep()` or `clock_nanosleep()`.